# atom editor: list of `styles.less` options

Tags: atom-editor

Where can I find a list of the keywords for the `styles.less` configuration file for [Atom](https://atom.io/)?

There are many specific requests for highlighting one thing or another, but I cannot seem to find a general overview of the implemented keywords.

Answer (score 2):

The scope names are supposed to be based on the ones listed at the bottom of the this page (the sublime text ones are also based off this list)
https://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars

In practice, nothing fits perfectly. The most reliable way to get the needed scope is running `Editor:Log cursor scope` in the command palette, which will make a notification popup with a list of all the scopes at the cursor. You then need to pick the relevant ones, and prepend each segment with `syntax--`.

E.g., if the scope popup says `source.md, markup.bold.md`, you can target bold scopes with

```
atom-text-editor .syntax--markup.syntax--bold {
  color: red
}
```

And that's just for text; anything at all can be modified if you know enough CSS. Opening dev tools lets you use the selector tool to find anything you like in on the page the DOM. Targeting it in the `styles.less` file will let you apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the namespace for Sublime:

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html